# How to enable Mobile(GSM) network on Ubuntu touch nexus 4

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Have installed Ubuntu touch on my Nexus 4 today. but, there is no mobile network and not sure the GSM radio got enabled or not. Could you help me to enable the GSM radio to use it as phone.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile data support is still being worked on, it is one of the goals for making the phone "dogfoodable" by the end of May.  To keep up with the latest developments, join the #ubuntu-touch IRC channel on freenode where you can talk to developers and porters from both Canonical and the community.